# What does this error mean "The 'RetrieveMultiple' method does not support entities of type" in Dynamics CRM /api/data/<version>?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

When I try to execute the request to `GET ../api/data/<version>/officedocuments` and at least 10 entities, I get an error:

> {"error":{"code":"0x80040800","message":"The 'RetrieveMultiple' method
>   does not support entities of type 'officedocument'."}}

The same problem I faced when I was trying to get full JSON of specific entity records

> {"error":{"code":"0x80040800","message":"The 'Retrieve' method does
>   not support entities of type 'roletemplate'."}}

Can someone suggest me how can I list all entity records for example for `officedocument`entity and get full JSON for mentioned above `roletemplate` records?

Comment: Error clearly states officedocuments and roletemplate entities do not support retreivemultiple. I would recommend using retreive and see you shall get results.

Comment: How can I do this using /api/data/v9.0 endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its not allowed/supported means we cannot do it that way. So if you need that entity, then use the workaround of using web api with fetchxml.

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/roletemplates?fetchXml=<fetch> <entity name="roletemplate" > <attribute name="name" /> <attribute name="roletemplateid" /> </entity> </fetch>
```

Clear query is like below:

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="roletemplate" >
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="roletemplateid" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Similarly, Workaround for that query is using [ExecuteFetchRequest](https://crmtipoftheday.com/796/long-live-executefetchrequest/)

```
//Try with IOrganizationService
      var orgService = new OrganizationService(connection);
      //Works
      var orgSvcExecuteFetchResponse = (ExecuteFetchResponse)orgService.Execute(executeFetchReq);
      //Doesn't work
      var orgSvcRetrieveMultipleResponse = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

      //Try with CrmServiceClient:
      var crmSvcClient = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
      //Works
      var crmSvcExecuteFetchResponse = crmSvcClient.Execute(executeFetchReq);
      //Doesn't work
      var crmSvcRetrieveMultipleResponse = crmSvcClient.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));
```

[List of RetrieveMultiple supported entities can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrievemultiple?view=dynamics-general-ce-9).

Answer (score 0):

The hack from @Arun's answer doesn't work anymore. Using `fetchXml` results now in the same error.

On [Microsoft Dynamics 365 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328086(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it is explicitly mentioned that `roletemplate` and bunch of other entities are for internal use only and are not meant for developer use.